# How to inject $modalInstance depends on condition in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I used the same controller for UIBModal & non-modal, but error is needed to provide $modalinstance when controller call from non-modal

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has `$injector` service for manually adding dependencies. So in order to check a condition whether to load the `$modalInstance` dependency or not. We can use it.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', 
     ['$injector', function($injector) {
        var service;

        if (condition) {
            service = $injector.get('$modalInstance');
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are right. Angular has $injector service for manually adding dependencies. So in order to check a condition whether to load the $modalInstance dependency or not. We can use it.

Comment: how it looks like now :)

Comment: var modalInstance;
modalInstance = $injector.get('$modalInstance'); when i used modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); it returns error -  Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined

Comment: service = $injector.get('$modalInstance'); it return Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance